# Still receiving email in Firebase about database expiring despite updating the Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am fairly new to Firebase Firestore, and this email states that my database will expire. I modified my rules one day ago, however, I still receive this email.

Here is the email sent to me:

[image: Email sent to me image]

Over here are the rules I updated for Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /dishes/{dish} {
     allow write: if request.auth != null;
    allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

And over here are the test mode rules (before the update):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 1, 27);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand, I have already updated my Firestore Rules, but I still receive that my database will expire soon. Any help would be great!

PS:
I am still new to Firebase/Firestore

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: When did you change your rules? It may take a day or so before the alerts stop coming.

Comment: just yesterday.